# Combinations of list of tuples with alternative values

Tags: python

I defined a dictionary which gives a list of alternative choices for tuples as :

```
d = {(2, 1): [(2, 1)],
     (1, 2): [(1, 2)],
     (2, 0.5): [(2, 1), (2, 0.5)],
     (0.5, 2): [(0.5, 2), (1, 2)],
     (0.5, 0.5): [(0.5, 0.5), (1, 1), (0.5, 1), (1, 0.5)],
     (1, 1): [(1, 1), (0.5, 0.5)]}
```

For instance :

- each tuple `(1, 1)` can be `(1, 1)` or `(0.5, 0.5)`.
- each tuple `(2, 1)` can only be `(2, 1)`.

I also have a list of tuples (each tuple of this list is always a key of the dictionary `d`). For instance :

```
lst = [(2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]
```

I want to list all alternatives to this list using the alternative values provided by the dictionary `d`. 
For instance, alternatives to `lst` will be :

```
[(2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]
[(2, 1), (0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5)]
[(2, 1), (0.5, 0.5), (1, 1)]
[(2, 1), (1, 1), (0.5, 0.5)]
```

I'm sure I can do this with itertools and lambdas, but did not find any solution for now.

Comment: If you made your example easier by switching out the tuples for single values, I think you'd come up with the solution. There's nothing special about the values being tuples, here, it just makes it slightly more confusing to look at.

Comment: `list(itertools.product(*(d[k] for k in lst)))`

Comment: Using a `float` as a key can cause problems because the lookup will use `==` to compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [itertools product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the desired output.

```
d = {(2, 1): [(2, 1)],
     (1, 2): [(1, 2)],
     (2, 0.5): [(2, 1), (2, 0.5)],
     (0.5, 2): [(0.5, 2), (1, 2)],
     (0.5, 0.5): [(0.5, 0.5), (1, 1), (0.5, 1), (1, 0.5)],
     (1, 1): [(1, 1), (0.5, 0.5)]}

lst = [(2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]

from itertools import product
result = list(product(*(d[k] for k in lst)))
```

This produces a list of tuples. If you wish to have all values as lists instead, you can just iterate and access them in that way.

```
for val in result:
    print(list(val))

#Output:
[(2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]
[(2, 1), (1, 1), (0.5, 0.5)]
[(2, 1), (0.5, 0.5), (1, 1)]
[(2, 1), (0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5)]
```